# Установка целей в Яндекс.Метрике на блок "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2, yandex-metrika-api

На сайте установлен блок "Поделиться" от Яндекса.
Хочу отслеживать в Яндекс.Метрике посетителей, которые поделились сайтом в соц. сетях.

Блок "Поделиться" устанавливается след. кодом:

```html
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,twitter"></div>
```

Для отслеживания перехода по ссылке, в Метрике, требуется добавить событие на ссылку:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="yaCounter123456.reachGoal('SHARE'); return true;">Жми сюда</a>
```

В коде блока "Поделиться" ссылок нет. Как мне установить событие на ссылки, в данном блоке?

PS. хочу сделать не одну цель для всех кнопок из блока "Поделиться", а на каждую соц. сеть отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать кнопки самостоятельно, либо воспользоваться [API блока «Поделиться»](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/)

В первом случаи, например для *ВКонтакте*, кнопка будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```css
.first span {
  border: 1px solid #527397;
  color: #527397;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <span onclick="window.open('http://vk.com/share.php?url=http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630147/', '_blank', 'left=200, top=200, width=700, height=300'); console.log('Нажали..');">Поделиться в ВК</span>
</div>
```

Для наглядности: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgfnrwra/)**
Соответственно, теперь мы можем повесить `reachGoal()` куда хотим.

Второй вариант, использовать `api` блока *поделиться*. В частности, нас будет интересовать группа *hooks*, которая позволяет указать свои функции, срабатывающие при наступлении определенного события в блоке *Поделиться*.

```js
var myShare = document.getElementById('share');

var share = Ya.share2(myShare, {
  content: {
    url: 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630147/',
    title: 'Установка целей в Яндекс.Метрике на блок Поделиться',
  },
  hooks: {
    onshare: function(name) {
      console.log('Поделились в ' + name);
      // Тут, в зависимости от name, можем выполнять нужную цель.
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>

<div id="share"></div>
```